# Visual Studio Code Apache Cordova Debugging Using Android Emulator

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

This is the error message when debugging on emulator:

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\astef\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended
> setting) ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\astef\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> (DEPRECATED) 2 Command finished with error code 0: adb devices Running
> adb shell command "cat /proc/cpuinfo" on target emulator-5584...
> Command finished with error code 0: adb
> -s,emulator-5584,shell,cat,/proc/cpuinfo ...

The error messages keep repeating non-stop.

What is wrong with this? If I restart my computer it is fine, but after some times, these errors will come back, and I need to keep restarting my computer.

[image]